# Calling Youtube API with Spring Security OAuth Principal

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, spring-security-oauth2

I'm fooling around with the Google YouTube API Java Client Library.  I have written a Spring Boot service that you can log into with your Google account using the Spring Security OAuth. That's all working great.

Now, in a REST endpoint method I have something like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/thing")
public ChannelListResponse getAThing( Principal principal )
{ ... }
```

where the `Principal` instance is an instance of `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`.

Ideally, I would like to have my service make a YouTube API call with the logged in user's credentials, but I have not been able to figure out how to build a `GoogleCredentials` instance from a given `Principle` instance.

I know I can make a `ServiceAccountCredentials` from my API key file, and in fact I have that working, but I'm curious if it is possible to use the `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` (my `Principal`) to make the call on behalf of that credential. I effectively want to wedge in between the user and Google and be able to enhance/decorate additional data and ideally have it all be done using the user's credentials.

Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the official docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#googlecredential), for to construct a [`GoogleCredential`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential.html) instance, you have to have at your disposal a valid access token and have to proceed like:

```
TokenResponse tokenResponse = new TokenResponse();
tokenResponse.setAccessToken(accessToken);

Credential credential = 
    createCredentialWithAccessTokenOnly(tokenResponse);
```

where:

```
public static GoogleCredential
    createCredentialWithAccessTokenOnly(
        TokenResponse tokenResponse)
{
    return new GoogleCredential().
        setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);
}
```

According to [a tutorial already quoted on SO](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/06/using-spring-security-5-to-integrate-with-oauth-2-secured-services-such-as-facebook-and-github), the needed access token is obtainable from your `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` instance as follows:

```
OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService;
OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken;

OAuth2AuthorizedClient client =
    clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
        oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
        oauthToken.getName());

String accessToken = 
    client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
```

Furthermore, you may [follow this doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2Client-authorized-repo-service) for to see how to get the instance of `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService` referred above.

### Addendum

If wanting to depart from the deprecated `GoogleCredential` class I mentioned above and use the class [`GoogleCredentials`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-auth-library/latest/index.html?com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials.html) instead, then things seem to be simpler:

```
public static GoogleCredentials
    createCredentialsWithAccessTokenOnly(
         OAuth2AccessToken oauthAccessToken)
{
    AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(
        oauthAccessToken.getTokenValue(),
        Date.from(oauthAccessToken.getExpiresAt()));
    return GoogleCredentials.create(accessToken);
}
```

(there's no need to use `TokenResponse` anymore).

For what concerns attaching scopes to a `GoogleCredentials` class, I deem that to be unnecessary.

Note that any given valid access token by itself (already!) has attached a set of scopes. That set was specified during the OAuth flow. For example, you could invoke the following URL (e.g. in a browser, or by issuing `wget` or `curl` at a command line prompt):

`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`,

replacing `ACCESS_TOKEN` with a concrete access token, for to see the scopes attached to the respective token.

The JSON response obtained upon such an HTTPS `GET` method call will look like:

```
{
  "issued_to": "...",
  "audience": "...",
  "scope": "...",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "access_type": "offline"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @stvar. This gets me closer.  I am able to create the GoogleCredential using your suggestions.  GoogleCredential is deprecated now and I should probably figure out how to do it with the newer GoogleCredentials class hierarchy. Also, I need to specify authentication scopes for the API I want to call and the GoogleCredential base class does not support that. But I think you've essentially answered my basic question as to how to use the Prinicipal to authenticate.  Thank you again!

Comment: I hope `createCredentialsWithAccessTokenOnly` is now OK. (Cannot test it at the moment.)